# Mysql if statement in select between two data

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in my query :

```
Year | Entitle  | 
2020 | 4        | 
2021 | 2        |
```

How to do the conditional query if 'Entitle' is greater than other year then it will appear in new column. For example :

```
Year | Entitle  | Higher 
2020 | 4        | Yes
2021 | 2        | No
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Entitle DESC) = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END Higher`.

Comment: Please elaborate on `other year` and also include more sample data with at least 3 years, so we can see the pattern you want here.

Comment: @Akina thank you..at the moment can you give example if that 'case when' convert in where statement

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use variables but then the order will different since than you will be comparing against the previous row.

```
set @olden:=NULL;
select year,entitle,
  if(isnull(@olden),"n/a",if(entitle>@olden,"yes","no")) as higher,
  @olden:=entitle 
from table order by year;
```

Please note that assigning variables in a SELECT statement may not work in future MySQL versions

Comment: Note that this is a deprecated method